# How to train a RNN for word replacement?

Tags: text, replace, neural-network

I have some understanding of how to use a simple recursive neural network that reads a sequence of characters and produces another sequence where each character is a function of the previous ones. However I have no idea how to implement the sort of delayed output generation required to do word replacement.

For example, if we want to replace `bar` with `foo`, then we must wait to see `b`, `a` and `r` before generating the first `f`. Otherwise `baz` will be rewritten as `foz` or similar.

How would a network able to learn to replace arbitrarily long words look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibilities. For example:

1) use whole words as input, encoded either as one-hot input vectors or pre-trained word embeddings
2) use [bi-directional RNN](http://www.di.ufpe.br/~fnj/RNA/bibliografia/BRNN.pdf) that is aware both of previous and next characters at the same time